# Can you preserve leading and trailing whitespace in XML?

Tags: xml, parsing, whitespace

How does one tell the XML parser to honor leading and trailing whitespace?

```
Dim xml: Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.loadxml "<xml>1 2</xml>"
wscript.echo len(xml.documentelement.text)
```

Above prints out 3.

```
Dim xml: Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.loadxml "<xml> 2</xml>"
wscript.echo len(xml.documentelement.text)
```

Above prints out 1. (I'd like it to print 2).

Is there something special I can put in the xml document itself to tell the parser to keep leading and trailing whitespace in the document?

**CLARIFICATION 1**: Is there an attribute that can be specificed ONCE at the beginning of the document to apply to all elements?

**CLARIFICATION 2**: Because the contents of the entities may have unicode data, but the xml file needs to be plain ascii, all entities are encoded -- meaning CDATA's unfortunately are not available.

Comment: CDATA certainly is available. You might just have to use more than one per element value, though.

Comment: @michaelpryor: About all answers recommending "xml:space". This problem has nothing to do with xml:space, which controls how a parser treats whitespace-*only* nodes. The nodes shown are definitely not whitespace-only. See my solution, which is the only one that really treats the problem. Cheers,

Comment: The problem has *nothing* to do with CDATA. CDATA is only there at parsing time, in the infoset, it is no longer present and whitespaces *are* part of the infoset.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I commented, **all answers recommending the usage of the `xml:space="preserve"` are wrong**.

**The `xml:space` attribute can only be used to control the treatment of whitespace-only nodes**, that is text nodes composed **entirely** of whitespace characters.

This is not at all the case with the current problem.

In fact, the code provided below correctly obtains a length of 2 for the text node contained in:

```
<xml> 2</xml>
```

**Here is the VB code that correctly gets the length of the text node** (do not forget to add a reference to "Microsoft XML, v 3.0"):

```
Dim xml As MSXML2.DOMDocument
Private Sub Form_Load()
Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.async = False
xml.loadxml "<xml> 2</xml>"
Dim n
n = Len(xml.documentelement.selectSingleNode("text()").nodeValue)
wscript.echo Len(n)
End Sub
```

If you put a breakpoint on the line:

```
wscript.echo Len(n)
```

you'll see that when the debugger breaks there, the value of `n` is 2, as it is required.

**Therefore, this code is the solution** that was being sought.

Comment: the xml:space="preserve" attribute worked though.  I don't know who deleted the answers that suggested it, but that worked fine for me.

Comment: @michaelpryor: More accurately, the answer to the orig. q. is: "No, nothing special needs be put in the XML document as the parser does not trim any non-white-space text node. Simply use the "nodeValue" property and do not use the "text" property.

Comment: On the line which assigns value to `n`, should we have `Len`?

Comment: @Jaywalker: Yes, we *do* have `Len` that returns the length of the string.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Dimitre Novatchev, for XML, whitespace is not deleted
at will by the parser. The white space is part if the node's
value. Since I do not speak Visual Basic, here is a C program with
[libxml](http://xmlsoft.org/) which prints the length of the first text node. There is
absolutely no need to set xml:space.

```
% ./whitespace "<foo> </foo>"
Length of " " is 1

% ./whitespace "<foo> 2</foo>"
Length of " 2" is 2

% ./whitespace "<foo>1 2</foo>" 
Length of "1 2" is 3
```

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char           *xml;
    xmlDoc         *doc;
    xmlNode        *first_child, *node;
    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s XML-string\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    xml = argv[1];
    doc = xmlReadMemory(xml, strlen(xml), "my data", NULL, 0);
    first_child = doc->children;
    first_child = first_child->children;        /* Skip the root */
    for (node = first_child; node; node = node->next) {
        if (node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE) {
            fprintf(stdout, "Length of \"%s\" is %i\n", (char *) node->content,
                    strlen((char *) node->content));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```