# How to put space character into a string name in XML?

Tags: android, xml, whitespace

i have defined some strings in the `strings.xml` file. Now I need to put some extra space between some numbers in the string. When I type extra space characters this is not showing on the application though.

Before:

```
<string name="spelatonertext3">-4, 5, -5, 6, -6,
```

And if I put extra space like this:

```
<string name="spelatonertext3">-4,  5, -5,   6,  -6,
```

It just looks the same on the app. How can I make space characters into the XML string?

Comment: Well, it looked the same in this page also...:) thing is i want some space between the numbers, how is that possible..?

Comment: Use code formatting to preserve the spaces (& `<>` content) on SO. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - String concatenate - how to keep the spaces at the end and/or beginning of String?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587056/android-string-concatenate-how-to-keep-the-spaces-at-the-end-and-or-beginnin)

Answer (score 506, accepted):

to use white space in xml as string use `&#160;`. XML won't take white space as it is. it will trim the white space before setting it. So use `&#160;` instead of single white space

Comment: This doesnt work with wrap_content of a textview, when the space occurs at the end of the text.  The textview does not maintain the width that is taken up by the 'space' character.

Comment: This will add a non-breakable space. It is different from a regular space and will not work well with certain functions (XPath's `normalize-space`, for example). Try using `&#032;` (regular space) instead of `&#160;`. @toobsco42

Comment: I had to use `&#160;` instead of `\u0020` to place a non-breaking space after the area code in a phone number. Otherwise, the phone number was being wrapped at the end of the line after the area code's trailing parenthesis.

Comment: &#032; is ok if you need 1 space. If you put several ones (&#032;&#032;...) they are trimmed to 1. I think that it is the same behaviour as a normal blank space so it seems useless. If found also suggestion about &#009; (supposed to be a tab character) : it displays nothing. &#160; works well, it is what I need, thanks ρяσѕρєя K.

Answer (score 78):

Insert \u0020 directly in the XML for a blank you would like to preserve.

```
<string name="spelatonertext3">-4, \u00205, \u0020\u0020-5, \u00206, \u0020-6,</string>
```

Answer (score 45):

Android doesn't support keeping the spaces at the end of the string in String.xml file so if you want space after string you need to use this unicode in between the words.

> \u0020

It is a unicode space character.

Comment: This worked for me using Android Studio 3.6.2 compiled to Android 4.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

This should work as well. Use quotes to maintain space

```
<string name="spelatonertext3">"-4,  5, -5,   6,  -6,"</string>
```

Comment: This is the cleanest (easiest to read) answer in my opinion. Unfortunately most people probably don't make it this far down the answer list before moving on.

Comment: This should be upvoted more. Very clean and readable, no unicode bs

Answer (score 14):

As already mentioned the correct way to have a space in an XML file is by using `\u0020` which is the unicode character for a space.

Example:

```
<string name="spelatonertext3">-4,\u00205,\u0020-5,\u00206,\u0020-6</string>
```

Other suggestions have said to use `&#160;` or `&#032;` but there is two downsides to this. The first downside is that these are ASCII characters so you are relying on something like a TextView to parse them. The second downside is that `&#160;` can sometimes cause strange wrapping in TextViews.

Answer (score 11):

Put `&#160;` in string.xml file to indicate a single space in an android project.

Answer (score 9):

Space variants:

```
<string name="space_demo">|&#x20;|&#x2009;|&#x200A;|</string>
```

| SPACE | THIN SPACE | HAIR SPACE |

Comment: This is the sweetest and awesomest one

Answer (score 7):

You can use following as well

```
<string name="spelatonertext3"> "-4,  5, -5,   6,  -6, "> </string>
```

Put anything in `" "`(quotation) with space, and it should work

Comment: Put anything in " "(quotation) with space, and it should work: THIS IS NOT WORKING

Answer (score 5):

The only way I could get multiple spaces in middle of string.

```
<string name="some_string">Before" &#x20; &#x20; &#x20;"After</string>

Before   After
```

Answer (score 5):

As explained here https://www.programmersought.com/article/33576744031/ use

Example

```
<string name="in">in &#160; </string>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to give Space Between 2 string OR In String file of android then do this in your string file .
Implement this before your "String name" that you want to show.
**\u0020\u0020**
For E.g..
**\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020\u0020Payment**

Answer (score 3):

As per your question if you want add spaces more than one in string resources their are many option to add spaces between character or word :

1.By default one space you can add directly in string resource file it working fine. but if give more than one space inside string resources file then it exclude that spaces.
    eg . -4, 5, -5, 6, -6,

2. If you want add more extra spaces inside string resource file then uses:-
   i. adding unicode after character like

   ```
       <string name="test">-4,&#160;&#160;5,&#160;&#160;-5,&#160;&#160;6,&#160;&#160;-6,</string>
   ```

ii.you can use "\u0020"

```
<string name="test">-4,\u0020\u0020 5,\u0020\u00205 -5,\u0020\u00205 6,\u0020\u00205 -6,</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>xml:space="preserve"</strike>

<strike>Works like a charm.</strike>

Edit: Wrong. Actually, it only works when the content is comprised of white spaces only.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/414631/can-you-preserve-leading-and-trailing-whitespace-in-xml)

Answer (score 1):

If the output is HTML, then in HTML multiple spaces display as a single space. To prevent this, use non-breaking spaces (xA0) instead of ordinary spaces.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio, you can open the strings.xml file and then click on "Open editor" and in the editor you can type any thing and **it will handle it for you to appear in the application exactly as you typed it**.

I know It may be late to write this answer, but It may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You want to it display like "-4,  5, -5,   6,  -6," (two spaces),you can add the following code to string.xml

> `<string name="spelatonertext3"> "-4,&#160;&#160;5,&#160;-5,&#160;&#160;6,&#160;&#160;-6,"</string>`

is display one space.